# Algorithms to compute the rank of a parametrized matrix

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, matrix-analysis, computer-algebra

Motivated by [my question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1128379/svd-of-a-parametrized-matrix) on Mathematics StackExchange and by [a question by Anirbit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37236/rank-and-kernel-size-of-parametrized-matrices) on the same site, I ask for some references on the problem of rank computation for a parametrized matrix. References for revelant problems (such eigenvalue computation for parametrized matrices will be appreciated as much).

**edit**: I'm particurarly interested in matrices of the form $Z(λ)=λA+(1-λ)B$, where $Α,Β\in R^{m\times n}$ and $λ\in(0,1)$. My first (unsuccesful) attempt to tackle this problems was to consider the analytic SVD of this matrix (because it is an analytic function of $λ$). In addition, if I somehow get able to compute the rank of $Ζ(λ)$, then, assuming that $rank((Ζ(λ))=k$, I also want to know the value(s) of $λ$ for which this result holds.

Comment: Do you have a precise class of parametrized matrices that you wish to investigate? this question seems to generic otherwise...

Comment: @Suvrit I'm especially interested in matrices of the form $Z(λ)=λΑ+(1-λ)Β$ where $λ$ is a real scalar variable taking values in a bounded interval.

Comment: @Kapoios You should edit the question to say this, and anything more specific about $A$ and $B$, which I think will trigger the option for high-rep users to consider re-opening it.

Comment: I think I've edited my question adequately to make it more targeted, so consider opening it. :)